# How To Change commets visibility in Excel with the help of excel Add ins using JavaScript APIs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, office-addins, excel-addins

i'm new to excel addins , i have to hide comments with the help of excel - addins , I have to add one toggle button there , while show/hide the comments , So is there any way I can achieve this functionality.

I Have Read the docs , but don't get any fruitful solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ribbon UI (commands) with an Excel web add-in. See [Create add-in commands in your manifest for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands) for more information and samples.

But `OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for hiding or showing comments at runtime, however you can add and remove comments programmatically. Read more about that in the [Work with comments using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-comments) article.

The [Excel.CommentCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.commentcollection?view=excel-js-preview) class represents a collection of comment objects that are part of the workbook.

The [Excel.Comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.comment?view=excel-js-preview) class represents a comment in the workbook.

As you can see currently that feature is not implemented in `OfficeJS`. You may consider submitting a request under aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions .